# Putting a plug on a light fitting

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bulb

I bought one of these: http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/50279373/

I would like to plug this in to the wall rather than hard wiring it in to the ceiling. Am I right in thinking I can connect this to a 3 pin UK plug (with a 3 amp fuse in it)? The cable only doesn't have earth but I'm not sure if this is a problem in this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use a decorative chain to support the horizontal lamp cord:

[image: swag lamp for sale on etsy]

This is called a swag  lamp in the USA.

Of course your installation would not have the vertical segment above the lamp. I have found that a decorative plastic chain is adequate in such cases.

Note that at the suspension points the cord remains within the chain and does not pass over the hooks. Hanging a lamp cord over a hook guarantees that it will eventually break.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get a plug and attach the two wires from the cord to the non-earth (ground) pins of the plug. Look for something like this - you strip some insulation off the end of your cord, open the plug, attach the wires to the appropriate pins, and close the plug which also clamps the cord in place.

[image]

The earth pin is the large one, labeled `E` above. Connect your lamp wires to the other two pins.

This fixture's cord doesn't include an earth wire because it has no metal components. The earth safety conductor is there to ensure any components that would conduct electricity are not accidentally energized with voltage that could injure a person. When there aren't any conductive components -- except of course the ones intended to carry power to your light bulb -- there is simply no use for an earth wire.

A safety tip: Make sure you mount your fixture in a way that doesn't cause undue wear on the power cord. When mounting from a ceiling box this is not an issue because the cord is clamped in place at the ceiling and the lamp is not frequently moved. But if you're hanging this across something else, or in a way that it will frequently move / rub against another object, you risk wearing through the cord's insulation and causing arcing or a short.